# Rails 3: how to update has_one and has_many pointing to the same table at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Thanks for helping out a noob. I have the following relationships in two models:

```
class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :last_book, :class_name => "Book"
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reader
end
```

I want last_book to be the most recent book associated with reader.

Right now in my book controller I am creating book as follows with similar code in update

```
def create
  @reader = Reader.find(params[:reader_id])
  @book = @reader.books.new (params[:book])
  @reader.last_data = @book
end
```

I think this ends up writing book twice to the database.  Is there a cleaner/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_one` allows an `:order` clause, so you could do this:

```
class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :last_book, :class_name => "Book", :order => "books.created_at desc"
end
```

Then in your controller action you would drop one of your assignments

```
def create
  @reader = Reader.find(params[:reader_id])
  @book = @reader.books.new (params[:book])
end
```

Jeff Smith's answer is also correct.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your associations will really work quite like you are intending them to. The way you have your associations set up, the `Reader` model won't be able to determine which book is the `last_book`, since all the books associated to a particular reader will have the same reader_id.  Assigning a book to a reader with `reader.last_book = book` is really just setting the reader_id column on that book model to the reader's id.  That's the same thing that will happen when you add a book to `reader.books` as well, so there really isn't any differentiating factor here for it to figure out which book you mean when you call `last_book`.

You'll probably be better off just defining a method for the `last_book` association you are trying to model.  If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, `last_book` should be the most recently created book for a reader.  In your Reader model do something like this:

```
def last_book
  books.order('created_at desc').first
end
```

and remove this line

```
has_one :last_book, :class_name => "Book"
```

That should allow you to do something like `reader.last_book` and it will grab the most recently created book in the books association.  This way, you never have any reason to need to explicitly assign `last_book`, you just add the book to `reader.books` and when you need the last book just call `reader.last_book`.